Smoothing algorithms for daily weight measurements
I weigh myself every morning and am trying to lose a pound a week, but weight data randomly fluctuates by several pounds.
The question I want to answer is "Have I been sticking to the pound a week trendline recently, or am I starting to diverge from it?"
Visually it's very easy to determine if my weight data seems to be clustering around the line, or I'm diverging. I understand our visual faculties are very powerful, but are there mathematical methods that are nearly as good?

There are a variety of ways one could smooth over the weight measurements. Local averaging methods, such as a moving average estimator could be interesting, but also standard non-parametric curve estimation methods such as LOESS could be of interest. You might consider comparing to the target curves after fitting a smoothed estimate of your weights.
